# Passing an err to finally in a try catch statement

Tags: javascript, try-catch

I am trying to write an asynchronous array strict equal function that reports errors how I want it to.

Here's my function:

```js
ArrayStrictEqual = function (arr1, arr2, callback) {
    var arr2s = arr2.sort();
    var eq = true;
    try {
        arr1.sort().forEach(function (item, index, array) {
            if(!(_.isEqual(arr2s[index], item))) {
                throw new Error(arr1 + " is not strictly equal to " + arr2);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        if (err) eq = false;
    }
    finally {
        callback(err, eq);
    }
};
```

But, when I run this, it says, `Uncaught ReferenceError: err is not defined`.

I was going to initialize err to null before the try-catch. But this doesn't seem like the right thing to do. But, I'm not sure what the right thing to do is. Should I be going about this in a completely different way (i.e. not try-catch)?

Comment: I don't see the point of it in this example, why do you need the catch/finally at all here? You know when there's an error condition, call the callback from there.

Comment: What is asynchronous in your code?

Comment: Exactly, the code is not asynchronous at all.

Comment: I am using this with NodeJS/Mocha. The Mocha tests are asynchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`err` is only in scope inside the `catch` statement (see [Why do catch clauses have their own lexical environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15034864/1048572) for technical details).

You could simply do

```
try {
    …
    callback(null, true);
} catch (err) {
    callback(err, false);
}
```

though that might not exactly be what you want, as it calls `callback` again when the first `callback()` throws. To avoid that, we'd need `try-catch-else` like in Python, in JS you need an additional boolean flag for this.

However, throwing an error to break from a `forEach` iteration is just a horrible practice. Don't do this. Use [`.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) instead, it does exactly what you really want. Also, you might consider avoiding the mutation of the compared arrays, copy them before sorting.